# in function 'error' /root/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/trepl/init.lua:389: in function 'require'

Tags: python, centos, torch

Since i am not used to lua  , this error is hard for me to resolve. Can anybody give me a help...[image]

Comment: [root@deeplearn3 openface]# ./demos/compare.py images/examples/{lennon-1.jpg,clapton-1.jpg}
...class nn.Decorator has been already assigned a parent class

stack traceback:
 [C]: in function 'error'
 /root/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/trepl/init.lua:389: in function 'require'
 ...lib/python2.7/site-packages/openface/openface_server.lua:20: in main chunk
 [C]: in function 'dofile'
 /root/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/trepl/scm-1/bin/th:150: in main chunk
 [C]: at 0x00405810

Comment: I have a similar problem, but I get the message: ```bad argument #2 (invalid parent class name nn.Decorator)```. Posted an issue here: https://github.com/Element-Research/dpnn/issues/91

Answer (score 1):

I also received this error. The cause is due to some modules having been moved from `rnn` and `dpnn` over to `nn`.

I've created a pull request with the necessary changes, once they are merged you should update the `dpnn` package with `$ luarocks install dpnn` and you should be good to go.

Pull request is here: https://github.com/Element-Research/dpnn/pull/90

If you don't want to wait for these changes to be integrated then run the following:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:richardassar/dpnn.git
$ git checkout remove_duplicate_modules
$ luarocks make rocks/dpnn-scm-1.rockspec
```

Comment: The changes were merged https://github.com/Element-Research/dpnn/pull/90#event-1078673270

You should reinstall `dpnn` (and `rnn` and `nn` for good measure) and the problem should go away.

Comment: Use your method, the problem is solved,thank you very much